# PHP CURL is throwing 403 error for URL where same URL works in terminal using CURL , in browser and in postman

Tags: php, curl

I am facing very weired issue. One API URL working fine in terminal using CURL, WGET and same working browser, Postman and PHP exec function but not working using PHP CURL code. So there is no network issue. Something I am missing in CURL PHP call or something not allowing.

Code is simple PHP CURL :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'ANY_URL',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: text/html',
    'Cookie: ak_bmsc=FD8C3DE69E40A4C5DDAE330F260728D2~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQVbopFx/wBzaOAQAAe+NdPBdrcmBV8EcoZ2aCTbyfXmfqhWROo32ff8B4/8Pn3DYRniT5jVnZ7Xoh4U/HAQxOb/xutXrv9tjMMkoFbHDFXXCh6X9R8wXZLsBkgiDuR585gKO2I7MkwxZ5qQISPrESJJJfKdVtPXZdTsHuSYIO5M63GLD4m9Z6cRieNRhVp4eftLfBOxhOrg64xTg05bI3qB6/p1JDi5rpkbVF/1TmHwg4gKpN5TGB5L7YEir2lGdKzL5k6DzUSZJueF3Lz0vCM+cI4S0u3expGMZJlmIbfzsR6x1Vda7XoslAmFXDaZiP7Sk8sH5IcNSVFmsMnkWKdiBNp3U+R1t7pkYmGlM2BJossoqCMhyNUA=='
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: You could set up a php-script to dump the **http request header** plus **the request** for any connection.   Use that to record and compare header+connection for all clients. Then compare with the output from **php curl**.  You can also enable debug output.

Comment: If I were to use `https://www.google.com` instead of your placehold `ANY_URL`, the code would return the front page for Google. Is `$response === false`? Also, what do you get with `var_dump(curl_error($curl));` ?